# Get and Modify Iframe content in JS

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have iframe with src="externalLINK".
But if I do frame.contentDocument -> Return null

I tried to start node js server, with express and axios :

```
axios.get(link)
    .then(response => {
        res.send(response.data);
        res.status(200);
        res.end();
    });
```

But the "externalLINK" is generated by other website, and work only if the same browser opens it itself ( SO Iframe ).
So server will get 404 error.

Have you a idea ?

Comment: You cannot access the DOM of an iframe of a different origin. See: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: The externalLINK is not mine, and if I test api.allorigin.win/?url=externalLINK . That will doesn't work, because the link work only in the same browser. Not a proxy